# AngularJS: Deep linking without having to use partial templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deep-linking

I'm using AngularJs to develop an application which allows to explore complex data. Therefor the concept of different views (-> routing with partial templates / controllers) does not fit very well for me. My app has rather a certain state (search text + selected doc + flagA=1 + flagB = x + ...) which I want to reconstruct via URL. So I would like to call my app using an URL like:

```
http://domain/app/#/search/some text/some-doc-id-123/
```

This should map to a route '/search/:text/:docid/' and I would like to get an event where I get :text and :docid. There I would gather the required data and would modify the gui as needed.

Any hint how to do that in AngularJs? I could not find much in the official documentation. The best match via Google was http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm (and other articles in this blog), but I could not get their code working nor could I found documentation about the stuff they are using!?

Comment: Have you looked at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/ ?

Comment: Documentation is here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router